# Separate transaction logs in Neo4j Enterprise

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I'am trying to change logical logs out of the *.db folder to put this in another disk volume. However I don't see any option in the neo4j config files that will allow you to do this. It's possible to do this configuration?

My neo4j version is 3.2.1.

Thanks

Comment: please give an example of what logical log is

Comment: Inside the *.db folder is the database files, right? Inside this folder there is the transactions logs, property store, and other files as well. 

I want separate the log files and move outside this folder.

Comment: Like neostore.transaction.db.0
Look in the source code

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org%3Aneo4j+neostore.transaction.db&type=Code

you may have to do some AOP to duplicate the logs, if you do not want to rebuild your own version of neo

Comment: Pardon my curiosity @Jhonathan , but why do you want to do that ? 

Isn't storing all the cypher executed what you need ?

Comment: I'm testing performance improvements. Like in SQL DataBase, if you change the log file to other disk you get less I/O concurrency in one controller and increase your response time. Make any sense for you?

Comment: Theoritically yes, makes sense. However, I dont know much about how data is stored in neo. Cant help here. You hold a good blog post subject here

Answer (score 4):

No, it is - at this time - not possible to move the transaction logs to some other place. Note that while the term **logs** is technically correct, these files are essential to the integrity of the database (unlike a regular log it would be very unwise to delete them) and it is therefore logical that they live together with the actual datafiles.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: It's sad to read it Tom. I'll send a message directly to neo to know more about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see file

```
  conf/neo4j.conf
```

and line

```
 #dbms.directories.logs=logs
```

Comment: Jerome, this folder is only for debug and information logs. I want to move the transaction and logical logs.